# Update using joins

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How do I update this statement in SQL server?

```
SELECT *
From std_company
join std_company_receipt 
  on cmp_guid = lcr_cmp_guid
join std_receipt 
  on lcr_rcp_guid = rcp_guid
where cmp_guid = '704BEF57-2740-4E20-B666-60DD25D73DCA';
```

So something like:

```
    update std_Receipt
    set rcp_ForceUnitemize = 1
    join std_company_receipt on cmp_guid = lcr_cmp_guid
    join std_receipt on lcr_rcp_guid = rcp_guid
   where cmp_guid = '704BEF57-2740-4E20-B666-60DD25D73DCA'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I do an UPDATE statement with JOIN in SQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293330/how-can-i-do-an-update-statement-with-join-in-sql)

Comment: Your "question" needs a little tweaking. You don't mention what column you want to update, what to update it to, etc.  Some effort and a little searching the forum for existing solutions would be more beneficial than a "That did not help".

Comment: update std_Receipt
        set rcp_ForceUnitemize = 1
        join std_company_receipt on cmp_guid = lcr_cmp_guid
        join std_receipt on lcr_rcp_guid = rcp_guid
        where cmp_guid = '704BEF57-2740-4E20-B666-60DD25D73DCA'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a FROM statement.  You should also alias your tables so there is no ambiguity on what tables the column is related to.  The link I submitted as a duplicate shows all this.

I guessed on what columns related to what tables since you left that out.

```
UPDATE rec
SET rec.rcp_ForceUnitemize = 1
FROM std_Receipt rec
INNER JOIN std_company_receipt comp 
   ON rec.cmp_guid = comp.lcr_cmp_guid
INNER JOIN std_receipt rec2 
   ON rec2.lcr_rcp_guid = comp.rcp_guid
WHERE rec.cmp_guid = '704BEF57-2740-4E20-B666-60DD25D73DCA'
```

Comment: Thanks i ended using something a bit different but yes I was missing a few alias'